# Codeigniter : How to show logged In User Name in every methods (or view page) without repeating same code in every function

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to show logged User Name in every view page by storing data in session.

---

But i have to write same two line in every function..
I am getting user data but Is there other ways to do This. Because i Think repeating same code is not too well.

**Controller**

So, This is my index function where i have email and also a model which is used to get user data from database.

```
function index() {
            $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
            $data['details'] = $this->Perfect_mdl->get_login_user_detail($email);

            $data['items_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name();
            $data['title']  = "Hotels";
            $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('hotels/visa',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/footer');
        }
```

**Second function**

Now, Here Same thing i have to do for showing User Name

```
function visa_dashboard($item_id = NULL) {
        $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $data['details'] = $this->Perfect_mdl->get_login_user_detail($email);

        $data['title']  = "Company Lists";
        $result = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_company_list($item_id);
        $result1 = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name_in_dash($item_id);
        $data['items'] = $result1;
        $data['items_company_data'] = $result;

         $data['items_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name();
        // $data['items_company_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_company_list($id);
        $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('hotels/dashboard',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');
    }
```

I am very new in Codeigniter . How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the two lines in the controller's constructor and it's available in all the methods.

```
 <?php
 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->model('perfect_mdl');
        $this->email = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $this->data['details'] = $this->Perfect_mdl->get_login_user_detail($email);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I edited @ourmandave answer. Call those variables with pseudo `$this` as `$this->email` in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Vishal you can use `$this->email` and more to display in any function of welcome controller, pass that value from your method to view on

```
$this->load->view('view1',$data['session'])`;
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: `<?php 
    $name = '';
    foreach ($details as $row) {
        $name = $row->first_name;
    }
?>`  if($this->session->userdata('email')) {
                      echo ucfirst($name); 
                      }Shakeel this is i am doing to fetch data from data base and showing name in header.

Comment: you can see my controller where i am getting data from model. and passing the data in header

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to store frequent required data in session !
then define a user class but to make it more sample create a custom helper instead in `helper/custom_helper.php`
define a function like

```
function login_username(){
    $CI = &get_instance()

    $username = $CI->session->userdata('username');

    if (!empty($username)) {
        return $username;
    }else{
        $email = $CI->session->userdata('email');
        //here you can load model or run query to get userdata or 
        // username
        //then set it in session for next time you need
        $CI->load->model('Perfect_mdl');
        $userdata = $CI->Perfect_mdl->get_login_user_detail($email);
        $CI->session->set_userdata(array('username'=>$userdata['username']));

        return $userdata['username'];
    }
}
```

autoload custom helper in `config/autoload` 
now just call it where you want it

```
echo login_username();
```